# Mysql @count:= @count + 1 update column based on the sort order of another query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns **alias** (all are  lower case) and **ordering**

how can I set numbers 0 to x  based on column **alias** in alphabetical order ?

update column based on the sort order of another query  (select mytable order by alias )?

```
to get

alias         |   ordering
abf-ergterw   |   0
crdsv-dfgdfg  |   2
bggg-rgewrdg  |   1
dxgg-rgewrdg  |   3
```

something like

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE mytable SET ordering = @count:= @count + 1;
```

but based on column **alias**  a = 1, b= 2, c = 3, ....

thank you

Comment: I want to set the column alias in the database , I know how to sort a column

Comment: Define an AUTO_INCREMENT column!

Comment: sorry it was not my question

Comment: update column based on the sort order of another query  aa , ab, abc, abd, ...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did you try to use `ORDER BY alias ASC`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ORDER BY clause in an UPDATE statement:

```
SET @count = -1;
UPDATE mytable
SET ordering = @count:= @count + 1
ORDER BY alias ASC;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34e664/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY alias ASC) - 1 AS ordering
FROM tab
ORDER BY ordering;
```

And `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tab a
JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY alias ASC) - 1 AS ord
  FROM tab
  ) b ON a.alias = b.alias
SET a.ordering = b.ord
;
```

**[MySQL 8.0+ Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jczdyZqQ4kxRXL8xYpPN1Y/1)**

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY alias ASC)` will only work in MySQL 8.0+. And MySQL 8.0 isn't production ready jet.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I am fully aware of that

Comment: I want to update the column ordering and to set a number based on another sorted column
I want to update not to select

Comment: @ErickBoileau So where is the problem? You could easily use the result of SELECT for UPDATE

Comment: @ErickBoileau Here you go

Comment: @RaymondNijland `"And MySQL 8.0 isn't production ready jet"` MySQL 8.0+ is [generally available](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-8-0-generally-available/). So it's the best time to upgrade and move forward